# 301 redirects specific pages with get parameters and non-specified pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have my old website `old.com` and my new website `new.com`. I want to create 301 redirects in the `.htaccess` for some specific pages and some generic 301 redirects as well.

**Get parameter redirects:**

`old.com/a/test?u=blah` redirect to `new.com/a/test?u=blah`

`old.com/a/test` redirect to `new.com/a/test`

`old.com/a/test.php?u=blah` redirect to `new.com/a/test?u=blah`

As you can see the only thing that changed was the domain name. How can I redirect users to the new domain but also keep their get parameter the same. So regardless of what `u=`, it forwards the `u=` parameter to the new URL. Of course if there is no `u=`, it still redirects to the page (as per second example)

**Get parameter without putting get parameter**

`old.com/a/foo?u=blah` redirect to `new.com/a/foo`

`old.com/a/foo` redirect to `new.com/a/foo`

`old.com/a/foo.php?u=blah` redirect to `new.com/a/foo`

As you can see, it directs to the new domain but does not carry the `u=` parameter. Same applies for the second example.

**Redirect Directory**

`old.com/blog` redirect to `new.com/blog`

`old.com/blog/23452/how-to-tie-a-tie` redirect to `new.com/blog`

If the site is in the blog directory, regardless of what comes after the blog directory in the URL, it always redirects back to `new.com/blog`

I am unsure on how to do these types of specific redirects. I only understand how to direct a specific URL like so `Redirect 301 old.com    https://new.com`

Comment: Please do share your complete htaccess file in your question, thank you.

Comment: I suggest you read through the documentation of the apache rewriting module. Your questions are all answered in there. Take a special interest in the `QSA` and `QSD` flags you can use with a `RewriteRule`.